# Compile single .ts file to stdout

Tags: tsc, typescript3.0

I am looking to compile a single .ts file to stdout, something like this:

```
tsc foo.ts > foo.js
```

is this possible somehow? I want to control where the output goes without using a tsconfig.json file.

Answer (score 4):

```
tsc foo.ts --out /dev/stdout | another-program
```

It comes from [this discussion](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1226#issuecomment-169117305).